# Get input to alert box from multiple labels using querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to get the user input from 3 labels and display onto an alert box. I am trying to use the queryAllSelector to grab the 3 id's from the labels which works. But when I try to type into the boxes and press the button to display the alert box, it just says [object NodeList].

HTML

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form</title>
    <link href="form.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <label class="title">Title:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="form-scream1" name="Title"  placeholder="Enter Text">
        <br>
        <label class="title" for="body text">Body Text:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="form-scream2" name="Body Text" placeholder="Write Something...">
        <br>
        <label class="title">Button For text:</label><br>
        <label for="bodyy"></label><input type="text" id="form-scream3" name="Body Text" placeholder="Text">
    </form>
    <button onclick="getinput()"> platypus</button>
</div>

<script>
    function getinput()
    {
        const inputVal = document.querySelectorAll("#form-scream1, #form-scream2, #form-scream3");
        alert(inputVal);
    }
</script>



</body>
</html>
```